# How can I convert numerical classes to factors in WEKA?

Tags: classification, weka, discretization

In a dataset with numerical values in classes, for example like this:

> Class: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0

WEKA open the dataset understanding Class label as a numerical, but I need WEKA interpret that variable as a categorical variable.

I need to get something like this, but in WEKA:

```
data$Class = as.factor(data$Class)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NumericToNominal](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/NumericToNominal.html) filter.